# I am trying to make a python turtle game where I move the turtle using key press and am trying to make a collision system - trinket

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am making a game using key presses where I control the turtle (which is a car image) around a race track and I am trying to make a collision detection system where if the car goes off track the program ends/restarts. The track is actually an image and so is the car and I am using trinket to code. I also incorporated a timer system and I had a question, like I said earlier I was making a car race around the track and every time the car does a lap around the track I wanted the timer to reset but couldn’t figure it out because I realized that that would also require some sort of collision system. These are the images I was using for the track and the car. Note: I am using trinket so using photoshop I have compressed the track image to match the trinket window and I’ve modified the car image as well to fit on the track. Here are the images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbwGD.gif)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9XyN.gif)

I tried an if statement and said if bob.pos() <= (0, -3): and under the if I put exit() to exit the program/close it, it seems that it is not working though. Here is the code:

```
import turtle as trtl

import time
bob = trtl.Turtle()
screen = trtl.Screen()
screen.bgpic(“trek5.gif”)
timer = 0

screen.addshape(“car1.gif”)
bob.shape(“car1.gif”)

if bob.pos() <= (0, -3):
    exit()

move_speed = 7
turn_speed = 10

def forward():
    bob.forward(move_speed)
def backward():
    bob.backward(move_speed)

def left():
    bob.left(turn_speed)
def right():
    bob.right(turn_speed)

bob.penup()

screen.onkey(forward, “Up”)
screen.onkey(forward, “Down”)
screen.onkey(forward, “Left”)
screen.onkey(forward, “Right”)
screen.listen()

while(True):
    print(timer)
    timer += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. Describe clearly what is desired and what is seen. Anyway I guess you want to test if ```bob``` is inside a region? Then I recommend to use a rectangular region ```(x, y, w, h)``` and check like ```0 < bob.xcor() - x < w and 0 < bob.ycor() - y < h```. And you should call ```turtle.mainloop()```. See [this](https://python-forum.io/thread-37212.html?highlight=tetris) for using a timer.

Comment: Thanks, so to  test if bob is inside a region or not, I would have substitute the variables for coordinates in the code you helped with above right?

Comment: Yes. Think about a rectangle of width ```w```, height ```h``` and the coordinate of its lower left corner (x, y).

Comment: So if I want to collide to anything under the x axles for example, then how would I write the numbers

Comment: You mean testing if ```bob``` is below the x axis? Then do like ```bob.ycor() < 0```.